# URL to specific time in video file

Tags: url, video, browser

Is it possible to create a URL that points to a specific timestamp in a video file? I.e. I have a video URL like https://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4 and I want to construct a URL that starts playback at 0:54 in the video. Is that possible somehow?

Clarification: this question is not about videos on Youtube or Vimeo, but about standalone video files that are provided by some other server, and that are played back by the built-in video player of modern browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [Media Fragments URI spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/) that appears to be [supported at least for this particular use case in most major browsers](https://caniuse.com/media-fragments).

This link should take you to the 50th second: https://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4#t=50

This link should take you to the 50th second and only play for one second: https://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4#t=50,51